# Ruby: how to decorate a method with memoization?

Tags: ruby, memoization

Suppose I have a class in Ruby:

```
class Test
  def method(arg1, arg2)
    return arg1+arg2
  end

  memoize :method
end
```

And I want to memoize its results. So for debug purposes I modified the class like this:

```
class Test
  def method(arg1, arg2)
    puts 'sth to make sure the method was executed'
    return arg1+arg2
  end
  ...
end
```

And wrote a test that calls the method with same args, to see what get's outputted... and well the method is not memoized. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is defining the `memoize` method?

Comment: +1 didn't know about this gem before!

Comment: You may want to avoid using `Test` as a class name, in case you wish to use test/unit later on.

Comment: This is not exactly the code I was really testing, but thanks for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`memoize :method` inside the class body, memoizes the method `Test.method`. However you want to memoize the instance method `Test#method`. To do this use `memoize :method` inside `Test`'s initialize method. (Make sure you include the `Memoize` module into `Test` first).

Answer (score 0):

There's a screencast on metaprogramming with several examples for memoization:

http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming (Episode 5: Nine Examples)

Code:

http://media.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/code/v-dtrubyom-v-05-code.tgz

Comment: He's not asking how to write a memoize method. He's asking how to use the memoize method from the memoize gem, or more specifically why his attempt at using that method did not succeed.